# Error in Loading UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tableview

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.nameList.count;

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
        //   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
        // reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    //Setup the cell
     NSString *cellValue=[ListofItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text=cellValue;
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.nameList              objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

Hi guys,
I have these codes and I cant see my values in my tableview.?And it says this:'program received signal sigabrt'
Can you help me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 return self.nameList.count;
```

which is the value of nameList.count when tableview numberOfRowsInSection is called? Try to set it to a fixed value just to test. Maybe you are not setting namelist properly.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;

}
```